# laupiFrpar/LopiPusherBundle Configuration for Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, pusher

I got this error:

```
Invalid configuration for path "lopi_pusher": Either url or app_id, key and secret needs to be set.
```

With this pusher_php_server.yaml:

```
services:
    Pusher\Pusher:
        public: true
        arguments:
            - '%env(PUSHER_KEY)%'
            - '%env(PUSHER_SECRET)%'
            - '%env(PUSHER_APP_ID)%'
```

And these variables defined on .env as PUSHER_HOST=api-eu.pusher.com etc ...

Also I'd need to config:

```
        timeout: '%env(PUSHER_TIMEOUT)%'
        debug: '%env(PUSHER_DEBUG)%'
        scheme: '%env(PUSHER_SCHEME)%'
        port: '%env(PUSHER_PORT)%'
        host: '%env(PUSHER_HOST)%'
        cluster: '%env(PUSHER_CLUSTER)%'
        auth_service_id: my_channel_authenticator
```

But don't know where...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see recipe for this bundle so you have to create configs by yourself.

Create `lopi_pusher.yaml` in `config/packages` dir with following contents:

```
lopi_pusher:
    # Default configuration
    scheme: '%env(PUSHER_SCHEME)%'
    host: '%env(PUSHER_HOST)%'
    port: '%env(PUSHER_PORT)%'
    cluster: '%env(PUSHER_CLUSTER)%'
    timeout: '%env(PUSHER_TIMEOUT)%'
    debug: '%env(PUSHER_DEBUG)%'
    auth_service_id: my_channel_authenticator
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried that under and did not work. When installed the bundle it ran a recipe.

Comment: The error was I was trying: parameters: lopi_pusher... avoiding parameters, it works altought I need to put hardcode false on debug param.